# Can Algolia search across multiple subdomains?

Tags: algolia

My company's site is spread out across several subdomains (e.g. help., blog., etc.). Can Algolia return relevant content from all of these subdomains when someone does a search?

For instance, say I have a SQL question. There's content that could answer that question on the blog and on help and on a few other subdomains. When I search "SQL" in the search bar, the results would be for pieces of content from all the different subdomains.

I believe Stripe does something like this, though I'm not sure what kind of search they're using. https://support.stripe.com/search?q=money

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely! Algolia Search API is domain agnostic, it's all about the data you push to Algolia. You can read the [getting started](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/getting-started/how-it-works) to better understand how it works.

In your case, you can push the content of all your subdomains to a single Algolia index and implement a simple JavaScript-based search targeting that index. You can then either build an [auto-completion menu](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/auto-complete) or a [full search results page](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/instant-search).